# Commercial Web Site That Uses Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Does anyone know of any commercial web sites that currently use Silverlight other than Microsoft's own sites?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The silverlight site has a huge showcase gallery, you can check that out.

http://silverlight.net/Showcase/

Answer (score 4):

Netflix instant streaming.

(Incidentally, the site linked above doesn't work on my machine.  Yay for completely ignoring web standards!)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  You need Silverlight to view it, or is the HTML all messed up on your machine (in your browser)?

Answer (score 1):

I like AOL's webmail client.
http://ria.mail.aol.com/
It is still in beta, but it is fast.

Answer (score 0):

I found another awesome Silverlight webmail client - called Silvermail:

http://silvermail.com.au

It's pretty slick and really fast, and it is totally free for use in the public domain... I use it with gmail because our corporate firewall won't let me check email while at work, plus I find the gmail interface too confusing... Silvermail is really simple.

A couple of friends have used it successfully for POP3 and it also works with Hotmail and Yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

This Silverlight site used to work with Moonlight in the 2008, 2009 era--that was at least 2 versions of Moonlight ago: http://www.recreation.gov/camping/Furnace_Creek_Ca/r/campgroundDetails.do?contractCode=NRSO&parkId=70978&topTabIndex=CampingSpot .   I just downloaded the latest version of Moonlight 3.99.0.3 and it doesn't work.  Silverlight is used just for the map option, so click on the button labelled Facility Map.  It is just about in the center of the first page (top to bottom and side to side).